# Converting KML to GeoJson

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, kml, geojson

I'm having huge issues doing this so once again i come for help.

I have this massive file which contains all the DMA's for Nielson what i need to do with php somehow is parse through each  and get the data from  and  the coordinates but they have to be outputted in this format

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "",
    "properties": {
        "dma": "514",
        "name": "Buffalo, NY"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [-79.761951, 42.269861],
                [-79.14959, 42.553193],
                [-79.048361, 42.691959],
                [-78.853455, 42.783961],
                [-78.943961, 42.978357],
                [-78.881611, 43.02363],
                [-78.880756, 43.02955],
                [-78.890068, 43.045268],
                [-78.946342, 43.072051],
                [-79.06977, 43.085841],
                [-79.06467, 43.262754],
                [-78.520257, 43.372277],
                [-77.994839, 43.36526],
                [-77.997291, 43.132981],
                [-77.905934, 43.133562],
                [-77.951044, 43.039544],
                [-77.904562, 43.023492],
                [-77.95633, 42.667882],
                [-78.060469, 42.532888],
                [-77.722965, 42.471217],
                [-77.749931, 41.998782],
                [-77.609815, 41.999367],
                [-77.59813, 41.478577],
                [-78.050728, 41.475103],
                [-78.203422, 41.618157],
                [-78.956057, 41.623863],
                [-78.918856, 41.998119],
                [-79.761374, 41.999068],
                [-79.761951, 42.269861]
            ],

            [
                [-78.933161, 42.963457],
                [-78.934961, 42.965657],
                [-78.934461, 42.964257],
                [-78.933161, 42.963457]
            ],
            [
                [-78.92426, 42.952357],
                [-78.92036, 42.954557],
                [-78.92886, 42.956457],
                [-78.92816, 42.955457],
                [-78.92426, 42.952357]
            ],
            [

                [-78.902609, 42.911768],
                [-78.901122, 42.929442],
                [-78.906739, 42.933805],
                [-78.906259, 42.929557],
                [-78.902609, 42.911768]
            ],
            [

                [-79.064667, 43.078556],
                [-79.071667, 43.078856],
                [-79.073267, 43.080156],
                [-79.071267, 43.083356],
                [-79.064667, 43.078556]

            ],
            [

                [-78.946165, 42.956954],
                [-79.015493, 42.990871],
                [-78.999465, 43.064756],
                [-78.89966, 43.041057],
                [-78.943945, 42.995081],
                [-78.946165, 42.956954]

            ],
            [

                [-78.88566, 43.023557],
                [-78.88836, 43.031957],
                [-78.88826, 43.034457],
                [-78.882868, 43.030771],
                [-78.88566, 43.023557]

            ],
            [

                [-78.956761, 42.958757],
                [-78.961462, 42.959357],
                [-78.963462, 42.961057],
                [-78.958362, 42.961457],
                [-78.956761, 42.958757]

            ]
        ]

    }
  }
]}
```

anyone have any idea how to do this correctly and efficiently i've been stuck on this for about 2 days with no success

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a tool which can convert (standard) KML to geoJSON (see link below). Its written in nodejs, though.

https://github.com/tmcw/togeojson#readme

Comment: Has anybody been able to make this work?  My data is in a javascript variable, and I just can't figure out the right format for the call.  I've seen the example at `http://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/` with the line `out.value = JSON.stringify(toGeoJSON[format.value]((new DOMParser()).parseFromString(input.value, 'text/xml')), null, 4);` but it doesn't make sense.. what I'm not getting is the really obtuse format of the `toGeoJSON = (function() {...` calls

Answer (score 3):

### KMZ to KML

KMZ is essentially a ZIP archive. Just use any zip tool to unzip the contained KML. Windows users might need to change the file extension to `.zip`.

### KML to GeoJSON

Use the Python utility `kml2geojson`:

```
$ pip install kml2geojson --user
$ k2g input.kml output_directory
```

### What's not working

- ogr2ogr: Can't deal with multiple layers in KML

Answer (score 1):

In response to the recent answer- iterating over each KML layer works as a fine workaround, comes up a lot when cleaning data in Python and R, and I guess could work for any language.

For example, in R and using GDAL it would look something like:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
```

```
data <- "INPUT KML"
kml_Layers <- ogrListLayers(data)
iterate <- length(kml_Layers) 

iterate_layers <- function(i){
      layer_i <- st_read(data, kml_Layers[i])
      return(layer_i)
    }

loops <- 1:iterate
Result_data <- lapply(iterate_layers, loops)
results <- ldply(Result_data)

writeOGR(results, "Data_geojson", layer="Data_geojson", driver="GeoJSON")
```

I know this isn't PHP, but it started saving me a lot of time once I started approaching KML this way.

Answer (score 0):

**KMZ to GeoJson**

```
            kmz = ZipFile("demo.kmz", 'r')
            kmz.extractall()
            os.rename('doc.kml','demo.kml')
            kml2geojson.main.convert('demo.kml', '')
```

**KML to GeoJson**

```
kml2geojson.main.convert('demo.kml', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This might halp in node.js

```js
const tj = require('@mapbox/togeojson');
const JSZip = require('jszip');
const parser = new DOMParser();

          fetch(url)
          .then( response => response.blob() )
          .then( blob =>{
              var reader = new FileReader() ;
              reader.onload = function(){ 
                console.log(this.result) ;
                var zip = new JSZip();
                JSZip.loadAsync(this.result.split(',')[1], {base64: true}).then(zip=>{
                  console.log(zip.files);
                  zip.file("doc.kml").async("text").then(function (text) {
                    var kml = parser.parseFromString(text, "application/xml");
                    var converted = tj.kml(kml);
                   
                 

                });
              } ;
              reader.readAsDataURL(blob) ;
          }) ;
```